# Set form action dynamically using computed property

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to send form to certain action, based on `select` value.

I have such template:

```html
<template>
    <form method="post" :action="myRoute" ref="myForm">
        <select @change="entitySelected" v-model="selected">
            <!-- -->
        </select>
    </form>
</template>
```

I'm trying to set up form action dynamically when new `select` value is appeared:

```js
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                selected: '',
            }
        },
        computed: {
            myRoute: function () {
                return 'example.com/'+this.selected
            }
        },
        methods: {
            entitySelected(event) {
                console.log(this.$refs.myForm.action) //<- action is 'example.com' without selected value
                console.log(this.selected) //<- this value is as expected
                this.$refs.myForm.submit()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What's wrong?

P. S. Browser - Firefox

Comment: Everything seem to be fine, it should work properly this way.

Comment: Try `this.$nextTick( () => console.log(this.$refs.myForm) )` in the `entitySelected` method to see what happens.

Comment: @Slim `undefined`. Bu the way, I discovered that `@change` is triggered before `computed` is recalculated...

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue here, i copied your code in this jsfiddle and it works just fine : https://jsfiddle.net/2zjrqpd3/

Comment: Oh sorry, just found out that it behaves differently on Firefox

Comment: @Okba thanks, I've updated my question (specified browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best way, but it works:

```js
userSelected(event) {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
        this.$refs.backdoor.submit()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setAttribute()` when updating the selected value :

```
this.$refs.myForm.setAttribute('action', this.myRoute);
```